# Variable length regex lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, search, preg-replace, lookbehind

My regex is below:

```
(?<![\s]*?(\"|&quot;)")WORD(?![\s]*?(\"|&quot;))
```

As you can see, I am trying to match all instances of WORD unless they are inside "quotation marks". So...

```
WORD <- Find this
"WORD" <- Don't find this
"   WORD   " <- Also don't find this, even though not touching against marks
&quot;WORD&quot;  <- Dont find this (I check &quot; and " so works after htmlspecialchars)
```

I beleive my regex would work perfectly IF I did not receive the error:

```
Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
```

Is there any way to do what I intend, considering the limitations of lookbehind?

If you can think of any other way let me know.

Many many thanks,

Matthew

p.s. The WORD section will actually contain Jon Grubers URL detector

Comment: @Qtax mentioned a good question:  are you trying to replace the detected words with something?

Comment: Also:  I think the regular expression you were trying to build is more like: `(?<!("|&quot;)\s*)WORD(?![\s]*(\"|&quot;))` there's no need to make the space capture lazy, and your space/quote terms were flipped in the lookbehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. This will work as long as the quotes are correctly balanced, because then you know you're inside a quoted string iff the number of quotes that follow is odd, thereby making the lookbehind part unnecessary:

```
if (preg_match(
'/WORD             # Match WORD
(?!                # unless it\'s possible to match the following here:
 (?:               # a string of characters
  (?!&quot;)       # that contains neither &quot;
  [^"]             # nor "
 )*                # (any length),
 ("|&quot;)        # followed by either " or &quot; (remember which in \1)
 (?:               # Then match
  (?:(?!\1).)*\1   # any string except our quote char(s), followed by that quote char(s)
  (?:(?!\1).)*\1   # twice,
 )*                # repeated any number of times --> even number
 (?:(?!\1).)*      # followed only by strings that don\'t contain our quote char(s)
 $                 # until the end of the string
)                  # End of lookahead/sx', 
$subject))
```

Comment: What about `This string makes me mad. "word\""`?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: Right, this regex doesn't check for escaped quotes. It can be modified to handle those, if necessary.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks, I am testing this new in my project, will let you know how it works

Comment: This seems to be working very well! I will be sure to test both answers but so far so good. May I ask - does your answer require SX modifiers? As that may cause issues with my existing pattern.

Comment: Also the only type I find does not work with your code is the combination of --- **word "word"** --- on the same line as unfortunately, while the second is correctly ignored, the first is also which should be a hit

Comment: My mistake - I simply formated wrong. It now works PERFECTLY :) Please see http://www.myregextester.com/?r=cf653ff3 for an example of my final solution. So grateful for this, thank you, thank you, thank you. I really feel I learnt something too.

Comment: @mrmrw: Great to hear it. Sorry for not answering sooner, I was away from home for a while. I guess you've found the answer to your question about modifiers (the `s` modifier only matters if your quoted strings may span several lines).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing quoted strings, then searching through what remains.

```
$noSubs = preg_replace('/(["\']|&quot;)(\\\\\1|(?!\1).)*\1/', '', $target);
$n = preg_match_all('/\bWORD\b/', $noSubs, $matches);
```

The regex I used to replace quoted strings above treats `&quote;`, `"` and `'` as separate string delimiters.  For any given delimiter, your regex looks more like this:

```
/"(\\"|[^"])*"/
```

So, if you want to treate `&quot;` as equivalent to `"`:

```
/("|&quot;)(\\("|&quot;)|(?!&quot;)[^"])*("|&quot;)/i
```

If you then want to also handle single quoted strings (assuming there are no words with apostrophes):

```
/("|&quot;)(\\("|&quot;)|(?!&quot;)[^"])*("|&quot;)|'(\\'|[^'])*'/i
```

Careful when escaping these to be put in to PHP strings.

EDIT

Qtax mentioned you may be trying to replace the matched WORD data.  In that case, you could easily tokenize the string with a regex like this one:

```
/("|&quot;)(\\("|&quot;)|(?!&quot;)[^"])*("|&quot;)|((?!"|&quot;).)+/i
```

Into quoted strings and unquoted segments, then build a new string with your replace operating on only the unquoted sections:

```
$tokenizer = '/("|&quot;)(\\\\("|&quot;)|(?!&quot;)[^"])*("|&quot;)|((?!"|&quot;).)+/i';
$hasQuote = '/"|&quot;/i';
$word = '/\bWORD\b/';
$replacement = 'REPLACEMENT';
$n = preg_match_all($tokenizer, $target, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$newStr = '';
if ($n === false) {
    /* Print error Message */
    die();
}
foreach($matches as $match){
    if(preg_match($hasQuote, $match[0])){
        //If it has a quote, it's a quoted string.
        $newStr .= $match[0];
    } else {
        //Otherwise, run the replace.
        $newStr .= preg_replace($word, $replacement, $match[0]);
    }
}

//Now $newStr has your replaced String.  Return it from your function, or print it to
//your page.
```

Comment: It's a way, but wouldn't work if you want to replace those quotes with something for example. Btw, I think `'\\\1'` has the value `\\1`, which PCRE interprets to match a plain backslash followed by a `1`. Maybe you meant `'(?:\\\\.|(?!\1).)*'`.

Comment: I don't think so - single quoted strings in php don't allow escape sequences, except for `\'`.  But I'm honestly not sure.  Let me check the docs ... (time lapse)... you're right.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single  `'\''` or `'\\'`.  I'll update that in a minute.

Comment: @Qtax - you mean if you wanted to replace the detected words with something?  You could easily create a more programatic way of doing that.  Personally, I'd tokenize the string into "quoted" and "not quoted" substrings, then run a replace on the "not quoted" bits.  Good call - if that's the use case, mrmrw, let us know.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks, I am testing this new in my project, will let you know how it works

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer - I think in this instance Tims answer is the one I will go for as I am (while experienced a lot with HTML/CSS/JS/PHP) rather new to regex and Tim's is perhaps a bit easier for me to follow. But still, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU for your answer. This is an amazing place and you are an amazing person. I intend to use my freetime to contribute back to stackoverflow as often as possible. So thanks again.